# Associating class properties to table columns in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

In a project I work on there is a C# library containing business objects which are related to the backing database tables/stored procedures.

We imported the code into EA model (where we already have database model) and now I'd like to show dependency between a class and a table (or stored procedure output).

Since these are loosely coupled (i.e. only a portion of properties are shared between them) I'd like to have a relation between a class A and table B and in the properties of this relation to have the mapping (A.a <-> B.a , ...).

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can draw connectors between two elements and then link one or both ends to an element feature (an attribute or an operation). Draw the connector, then right-click near the end and select Link to Element Feature.

You can draw any number of connectors between two elements, and link any number of them to any features at either or both ends.

You should note that this is an EA feature which is not in the UML standard. As such, it is also a little trickier to automate (the feature link is not documented in the API), but I've done it before for a client so it can be done. However, from your question I assume it's the manual case you're interested in.